# android In app billing fail You need to sign in to your Google Account

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I follow this guide http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial

If I  use default `SKU`, my fake purchase is successful.

```
  static final String ITEM_SKU = "android.test.purchased"
```

But if I try to make a real one,  I get `You need to sign in to your Google Account` error.

According to advices in SOF:
 1. I activated my purchase in `google play console`
 2. Copied `base64SecurityKey`
 3. Tried to create app in alpha testing mode I run the app on non-developer account
 4. Use the same ID of purchase item in code and console
 5. The app is `published`

Here's log:

```
D/TAG: In-app Billing is set up OK
D/TAG: Starting async operation: launchPurchaseFlow
D/TAG: Constructing buy intent for  be.motti.removead, item type: inapp
D/TAG: Launching buy intent for  be.motti.removead. Request code: 10001
```

After  click 'accept' :

```
D/TAG: Ending async operation: launchPurchaseFlow
D/TAG: Purchase canceled - Response: 2:Unknown
```

Can somebody help with it?

Comment: Did you add the non-developer test user to the list of testers in both the alpha testing page and in the main testers list in your developer settings?

Comment: @vedi0boy yes, but how can it affected? I have open alpha and linked it through the non-developer account.